# How to change `whitelist` to `safelist` in Jsoup 1.15.+ when using `Overzealous` at same time

Tags: jsoup

In my project, I update Jsoup version from 1.14.3 to 1.15.3. Due to **whitelist** is discard and now use **safelist**, I found **whitelist** in **Overzealous:Remark** is still being used.

Here is my code

````
return remark.get().convertFragment(safe)
    .replaceAll("\r\n", "\n")
    .replaceAll("\n\n```\n", "\n\n```java\n");
````

And here is Jsoup update note on Github.

```
  * Improvement: renamed the Whitelist class to Safelist, with the goal of more inclusive language. A shim is provided
    for backwards compatibility (source and binary). This shim is marked as deprecated and will be removed in the
    jsoup 1.15.1 release.
    <https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1464>
```

Due to I used overzealous at the same time, I meet this issue by accident.

```
public Remark(Options options) {
        this.converterLock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.cleanedHtmlEchoed = false;
        this.options = options.getCopy();
        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.basicWithImages().addTags(new String[]{"div", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead", "tr", "hr", "span", "font", "del", "strike", "s"}).addAttributes("th", new String[]{"colspan", "align", "style"}).addAttributes("td", new String[]{"colspan", "align", "style"}).addAttributes(":all", new String[]{"title", "style"});
        if (options.preserveRelativeLinks) {
            whitelist.preserveRelativeLinks(true);
        }
    ...
}
```

This message shows what I see after update jsoup version to `1.15.3`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist
```

Everything seems good until I upgrade Jsoup version to 1.15.3, I just want to build succeed.

By the way, The highest overzealous version in mvn repository is 1.1.0.

Comment: IMO, I try to use `extend` to avoid `whitelist`. but I don't know whether it work.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.